# disable Required Field Validators

Tags: asp.net, forms, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a form which consists of several requiredfieldvalidators and have 2 buttons an add and update button. i want to associate only 5 out of 13 requiredfieldvalidators with the update button and all with the add button is this possible since i am stuck with this problem.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why with an update the field is suddenly no longer required?

Comment: because some of the fields a user wouldnt be able to update but the administrator will

Comment: So how can a user insert them? You better make these fields not editable and leave the requirefield validator

Answer (score 1):

Are some fields related to the two buttons ?

If there are fields related to the add button and fields (but not the same) related to the update button, you can set the same ValidationGroup property on fields, validators and buttons that are related

if there are fields related to the both the add and the update button :

- either review your ergonomy... this sounds a bit strange
- or use a custom validator that will check the conditions of you own

Comment: there are some that have to be valid for both buttons but only one button will be clicked at the same time. the fact is that i dont know how to use custom validators

Comment: then start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.mobilecontrols.customvalidator.aspx). The main idea is to handle at least a server event on the validator where you can, in code, tell if it's ok or not. You can also implement a custom JS to handle the check on the client side the value, but it's a bit more complex (but you avoid having to wait for the click to validate). However, it sounds a bit strange to have a field that can be validated in some case but not in other. Can you explain a bit what you are trying to do (in fact, why the form is the same for add AND update) ?

Answer (score 0):

Seperate your controls into 2 divs, then use javascript to control the validators.

Say click "Add" enable validators for Adding, click "update" then just enable validators for updating.

I wrote some js code seems can meet your requests.
Iterate validators and enable these you needs.
then clear the screen,erase the error info.

```
$(function() {
      hidedivTemplate();
});

function hidedivTemplate() {
      $('#divTemplate').hide();
      $('#divAuto').show();
      goThroughValidators(enableAutoDIV_Validation);
}

function hidedivAuto() {
      $('#divAuto').hide();
      $('#divTemplate').show();
      goThroughValidators(enableTemplateDIV_Validation);
}

function goThroughValidators(func) {
      for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
            var validator = Page_Validators[i];
            func(validator);
      }
      //After the iteration, clean the error info on the screen
      $("span[class='errorleft']").hide();
}

function enableAutoDIV_Validation(validatorObj) {
      switch (validatorObj.controltovalidate) {
            case "<%=AAA.ClientID%>":
            case "<%=BBB.ClientID%>":
                  ValidatorEnable(validatorObj, true);
                  break;
            default:
                  ValidatorEnable(validatorObj, false);
                  break;
      }
}

function enableTemplateDIV_Validation(validatorObj) {
      switch (validatorObj.controltovalidate) {
            case "<%=CCC.ClientID%>":
            case "<%=DDD.ClientID%>":
                  ValidatorEnable(validatorObj, true);
                  break;
            default:
                  ValidatorEnable(validatorObj, false);
                  break;
      }
}
```

The full code snippet can be found here http://codelife.cybtamin.com/2012/08/enable-and-disable-asp-net-validator-by-javascript/